# creating dynamic pages in javascript and jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, web-applications

I am trying to dynamically create pages in jquery mobile with:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myarrayA = 
        ['/link1.pdf',
         '/link2.pdf',
         '/link3.pdf',
         '/link4.pdf',
                         .
                         .
                         .        
                    'link100.pdf']
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){                

        for(i=0;i<myarrayA.length;i++){
        $('body').append(' \
        <div id="link'+i+'" data-role="page">  \
        <div data-role="header"></div>\
        <div data-role="content">\
        <iframe id="mytester" src=http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com'+myarrayA[i]+'"></iframe>\
        </div></div>');}});
    </script>
```

The script works but it takes FOREVER to load! What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: How large are those pdfs? If you load them inside of a for loop inside of an iframe each then that could take FOREVER :P. Consider loading them on demand instead of eager loading them if they are too large.

Comment: This is not the right way of using this. Why cant u just make them download the PDF's to their phone? `location.href="link to PDF"`

Comment: Uh oh! You're using `.ready`..

Comment: @Omar - I think you found my problem.

Comment: Refrain from using `.ready` with jQM, use jQM events. Such as `pageinit`.

Comment: @Omar - is this the reason of why document.write doesnt work?